# Error: File to import not found or unreadable (Gulp, using WordPress Sage)

Tags: wordpress, gulp, roots-sage

`gulp watch` randomly crashes when doing minor CSS changes. The very same change will work one time (browser reloads and change shows up) but the next time (after undo and redo in text editor then save) `gulp watch` may inexplicably crash with the following error:

```
[03:53:21] Starting 'styles'...
assets\styles\main.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: partials/home_page
       Parent style sheet: D:/EasyPHP/www/pot/wp-content/themes/pot/assets/styles/main.scss
        on line 4 of assets/styles/main.scss
>> @import "partials/home_page";
   ^

[03:53:21] Finished 'styles' after 7.96 ms
```

... Considering the exact same change worked just fine seconds before. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to happen only to Windows users who work with Sublime Text. [Here's the solution to this particular issue](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/235): add `"atomic_save" : true` to user settings.